# Access Sonatype nexus artifact from nexus plugin after being uploaded

Tags: java, nexus

I want to access an artifact (zip File containing a delivery) uploaded to a sonaytype nexus 2.14.0-01 to unzip it in a tmp directory and examine its content.

I am able to  hook into the on handle request for the create action, however, at that time the artifact is not yet uploaded to the repository.

```
public void onHandle(Repository repository, ResourceStoreRequest resourceStoreRequest, Action action) throws ItemNotFoundException, IllegalOperationException
{
    log.info("got onHandle Request for " + repository.toString() + " " +   action.toString() + " " + resourceStoreRequest.toString());
    log.info("that is the file to process: " + resourceStoreRequest.getRequestPath());
}
```

Log entries:

```
2016-10-11 18:01:23,760+0200 INFO  [qtp1685232414-73] admin DeliveryRequestProcessor - got onHandle Request for M2Repository(id=deliveries) create ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='/fakepath/configurationmanagement/0.1/configurationmanagement-0.1.zip', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@3476eab3, parent=null}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[], appliedMappings={}}(GAVCE=fakepath:configurationmanagement:0.1:c=null:e=zip, for "deliveries" [id=deliveries])
```

but a call for

```
    repository.getLocalStorage().retrieveItem(repository,resourceStoreRequest)
```

is failing (naturally).

Is there any advice on what hook to use after a file is uploaded and can be processed?

Best regards,
Eduard

Answer (score 0):

I used a not-so-nice workaround to implement the needed functionality.

In the original class, I register a Listener to the EventBus.

```
@Named(DeliveryRequestProcessor.ID)
public class DeliveryRequestProcessor extends ComponentSupport
    implements RequestStrategy {

    @Inject
    public DeliveryRequestProcessor(final EventBus eventBus)
    {
       this.eventBus = Preconditions.checkNotNull(eventBus);
       eventBus.register(new EventBusListener());
   }
}
```

I have created another class, subscribing to all events nexus is sending.

```
@Named
@EagerSingleton
public class EventBusListener 
{
    public void onEvent (RepositoryItemEventStoreCreate e)
    {
        ... the functionality to access the item
        e.getItem() // -> that is the Storage Item I was looking for
    }
}
```

The solution has some drawbacks, e.g. the event fires multiple times and you need to ensure that the processing only is performed one, but for a first solution its acceptable (for me).

Best regards,
Eduard